# Why is the CAShapeLayer I create in draw not successfully animating?

Tags: swift, xcode, core-animation, uiviewanimation, cashapelayer

There are several S.O. questions out there about CA Shape Layers not successfully animating, and I've looked through them but I can't figure out what my error is (although I think it's a basic misunderstanding of how to use CA Layers.

I'm trying to draw 3 circles on the screen, and fill them up when a method is called.

In a custom UIView, inside my setup, I have the following code:

```
class ProgressBar: UIView {
        private var bubbles: [CAShapeLayer] = [CAShapeLayer(), CAShapeLayer(), CAShapeLayer()]
        private var positions: [CGFloat] = [0.25, 0.50, 0.75]

        private var mainRect = CAShapeLayer()
        private var progRect = CAShapeLayer()

func setup() {
        self.isOpaque = false
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        // initialize the main rectangle
        mainRect.fillColor = secondary.cgColor
        mainRect.strokeColor = primary.cgColor
        self.layer.addSublayer(mainRect)

        // initialize the "progress" part
        progRect.fillColor = primary.cgColor
        progRect.strokeColor = secondary.cgColor
        self.layer.addSublayer(progRect)

        // initialize the bubbles
        for i in 0...2 {
            bubbles[i].fillColor = (CGFloat(progress) < positions[i]) ? secondary.cgColor : primary.cgColor
            bubbles[i].strokeColor = (CGFloat(progress) < positions[i]) ? primary.cgColor : secondary.cgColor
            self.layer.addSublayer(bubbles[i])
        }
    }
```

And then, when the layout changes, I just modify the cgPath for each layer in layoutSubviews.

When I try to animate, I call this method on the custom UIView:

```
func fillCircle() {
        let newFill: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "fillColor")
        newFill.fromValue = secondary
        newFill.toValue = primary
        newFill.duration = 2

        bubbles[0].add(newFill, forKey: "fillColor")
    }
```

Can anyone point me to what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Answered - unfortunately, the problem was that newFill.fromColor takes an Any? object, and I was passing it a UIColor object while it required a cgColor object.